# Complexity of Exact Cover problem if containing a Set Cover means there is an Exact Cover

Tags: np-hardness, set-cover, exact-cover

As stated in the question, I'm interested in a variant of Exact Cover that is currently relevant to my research. Specifically, a variant where you are promised that if there is a Set Cover of size $k$, then there is also an Exact Cover of size $k$ (or less).

More formally, let us define the Exact Cover and Set Cover problems.

**Set Cover**
Given a collection $S$ of of subsets $S_i$ of a set $X$ and a target $k$, does there exist a subcollection $S^{\ast}$ of $S$ of size $k$ or less such that every element in $X$ is contained in $S^{\ast}$?

**Exact Cover**
Does there exist a Set Cover of size $k$ such that every element in $X$ is contained *exactly once* in $S^{\ast}$?

My modification is

**Pure Exact Cover**
For a given input, categorize the input into one of two cases:

1. There an Exact Cover of size $k$ or less,
2. There is no Set Cover of size $k$.

You are promised that if there is a Set Cover of size $k$, there is also an Exact Cover of size $k$

Is this Pure Exact Cover problem still NP-hard? Or at least, has this problem been examined at all in the research? I can't find anything, but I also have no idea what name it would have.

Comment: This is a generalization of the NP-hard **Perfect 3d Matching** problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's also NP-hard, because Set Cover on sets of constant size is NP-hard, and given an instance of Set Cover with constant-size sets, you can add all the (polynomially many) subsets of the given sets, and you will obtain a new instance which is equivalent (has the same min-size set cover) but also has an exact cover of the same size as the min-size set cover.

Comment: Thank you! This is a really cute reduction that I'm kicking myself for not thinking of haha.